# ffmpeg missing blend filter

Tags: android, filter, ffmpeg

I am working on android project using ffmpeg library. I followed instruction from: https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg to build ffmpeg library for android. All are OK.

Now, i am testing filters that corresponding to video filter of this library such as: drawtext, scale, pad, ... Most of them worked fine, but i have problem with "blend" filter.

I try with commands: **ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex blend=all_expr='if(eq(mod(X,2),mod(Y,2)),A,B)' -y out.mp4** and recieve error: no such blend filter.

Do you know how i configure to enable this filter?

Here is the output result:

```
ffmpeg version 0.11.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 27 2014 05:23:20 with gcc 4.6 20120106 (prerelease)
  configuration: --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --target-os=linux --enable-runtime-cpudetect --prefix=/data/data/info.guardianproject.ffmpeg/app_opt --enable-pic --disable-shared --enable-static --cross-prefix=/home/admin/workspace/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=/home/admin/workspace/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-3/arch-arm --extra-cflags='-I../x264 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags=-L../x264 --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --disable-doc --enable-yasm --enable-decoders --enable-encoders --enable-muxers --enable-demuxers --enable-parsers --enable-protocols --enable-filters --enable-avresample --enable-libfreetype --disable-indevs --enable-indev=lavfi --disable-outdevs --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network --enable-libx264 --enable-zlib --enable-muxer=md5
  libavutil      51. 54.100 / 51. 54.100
  libavcodec     54. 23.100 / 54. 23.100
  libavformat    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
  libavdevice    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
  libavfilter     2. 77.100 /  2. 77.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/videokit/in.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2014-03-04 08:53:01
  Duration: 00:00:15.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7055 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 6935 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 16:9, 17.18 fps, 34.42 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-04 08:53:01
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-04 08:53:01
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/videokit/7.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    encoder         : Lavf53.12.0
    comment         : Courtesy of National Geographic.  Used by Permission.
  Duration: 00:00:04.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1601 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1472 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
No such filter: 'blend'
Error configuring filters.
```

Thanks

Comment: I updated the console output. Please take a look Thanks

Comment: `ffmpeg version 0.11.1` This is ancient. Use a more recent version. Users are suggested to use `ffmpeg` from git master.

Comment: Thanks. I will update it and check again.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion LordNeckbeard. I built successfully

Answer (score 2):

Just you need put double-quote between blend=all_expr='if(eq(mod(X,2),mod(Y,2)),A,B)' and your final command must be look like this : **ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "blend=all_expr='if(eq(mod(X,2),mod(Y,2)),A,B)'" -y out.mp4** You need to becarefull to ffmpeg syntax. You can check [this](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) link for extra information.

Comment: It sounds like the fix for this issue was to update to a newer version, if this is the case, this answer may be erroneous.